# Why did I only get half a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounties, specific-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I answered this question and received two upvotes, but only got 50% of the bounty (was 100, got 50).

[Unique results from joined queries with NHibernate LINQ provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356862/1396203#1396203)

The accept checkmark's tooltip is:

> The question owner accepted this as the best answer 12 hours ago. This answer was awarded a bounty of 50 reputation

That seems to imply that the OP did mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Note that this question was asked before the awarding of bounties was separated from the process of accepting answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the bounty period ended, those two up-votes would ensure that you get half the rep automatically. If the OP accepted your answer, you should have gotten the full amount of rep.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that there is only one value for the 'Owner accepted answer' string.  It doesn't allow for the nuance with auto accepted bounty answers.