# Highest-ranked answer not auto-selected at end of bounty and now I cannot select any answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties, accepted-answer

I offered a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015288), but after the bounty expired, the only and top-rated answer was not auto-accepted. Now I don't have the option to accept any answer and the bounty points seem to have vanished altogether ... Is this a bug, expected behavior or did I do something wrong?

Edit: This all happened many days ago, so it can't be related to the [slight delay in auto-acceptance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13186). Or can it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any answer with fewer than 2 upvotes will not be auto-accepted; you have to manually accept it. This is part of the "contract," if you will, that starting a bounty gives you -- you're not *supposed* to let it run out, you're supposed to select an answer. This is by design.

Rules of bounties:

- [If a bounty is unresolved, you can never accept an answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/answer-cant-be-accepted-after-an-unresolved-bounty)
- [There are no refunds for unresolved bounties.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9902/what-happens-if-there-are-no-answers-to-a-bounty-question)
- [Auto-resolved bounties (where the asker does not select the answer) only gain half-rep.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21183/bounty-process-clarification)
- [Bounties currently cannot be extended if you feel you're not getting good answers.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22094/how-to-extend-a-bounty)

All of this can also be found in the FAQ:

> Once initiated, the bounty period
>   lasts 7 days. If you mark an accepted
>   answer, your bounty is awarded to the
>   answerer (do note that accepted bounty
>   answers are permanent and cannot be
>   changed). If you do not accept an
>   answer in 7 days, here is what happens
>   at the end of the bounty period:
>
> - The highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least
>     2 upvotes will be automatically
>     accepted. Half the bounty will be
>     awarded to the owner of that answer.
> - If there is no answer meeting the above criteria, and you as the
>     question owner have not opted to
>     accept an answer, you forfeit your
>     right to ever accept an answer to your
>     question.
>
> In any case, you will always give up
>   the amount of reputation specified in
>   the bounty, so if you start a bounty,
>   be sure to follow up and accept the
>   best answer!

Comment: Thx. I guess this is a case of RTFM on my end. It would have been helpful, though, to see the "2 votes minimum" requirement in the "popup" one gets when creating the bounty. If I had known, I would have marked the only existing one as answer before the bounty ran out.

Comment: I had exactly this happen myself. This question explained it for me. I wish I could select the only answer that was provided even though it never did receive 2 votes. :-(